# Why is it a good idea to store the result of the recursive call in a variable here?

Tags: java, recursion, memory

Here is what I mean.

Why Doing it this way
`int subtreeHeight = height(t.child(i));`

`if (subtreeHeight > maxSubtreeHeight)`

is better than

`if (height(t.child(i))> maxSubtreeHeight)`

```java
private static int height(XMLTree t) {
    int maxSubtreeHeight = 0;
    
    if (t.isTag()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < t.numberOfChildren(); i++) {
            int subtreeHeight = height(t.child(i));
            
            if (subtreeHeight > maxSubtreeHeight)
                maxSubtreeHeight = subtreeHeight;
        }
    }
    
    return maxSubtreeHeight + 1;
}
```

Comment: Avoiding the completely unnecessary overhead of having to calculate the same figure twice, perhaps? It's not clear why one method is really better than the other in practice, however, except if the calculation itself takes a material amount of time.

Comment: `subtreeHeight` is being used twice. It's as simple as one (recursive) function call vs two function calls.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do it right.

```java
private static int height(XMLTree t) {
    if(!t.isTag())
        return 1;
    
    int height = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < t.numberOfChildren(); i++)
        height = Math.max(height, height(t.child(i));
    
    return height + 1;
}
```

***P.S.** Using recursion for a big tree is quite dangerous from the memory usage perspective.*

I would recomend to use [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) instead:

```java
private static int height(XMLTree t) {
    if(t == null)
        return 0;
    
    Queue<XMLTree> queue = new LinkedList();
    queue.add(t);
    
    int height = 0;
    
    while(queue.isEmpty()) {
        height++;
        int size = queue.size();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            XMLTree node = queue.remove();
            
            if(node.isTag())
                for (int j = 0; j < node.numberOfChildren(); j++)
                    queue.add(node.child(j));
        }
    }
    
    return height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code:

```
int subtreeHeight = height(t.child(i));
if (subtreeHeight > maxSubtreeHeight) {
    maxSubtreeHeight = subtreeHeight;
}
```

is better than your suggested rewrite:

```
if (height(t.child(i)) > maxSubtreeHeight) {
    maxSubtreeHeight = height(t.child(i));
}
```

because in the event that the statement is true, you do not have to recalculate the depth of the branch to assign the value to `maxSubtreeHeight`. This makes the program faster.